# i am unable to make multiple directories at a time in my mac terminal

Tags: command-line, mac

i am unable to make multiple directories at a time in my mac terminal i.e. i wrote in command : "mkdir temp/thing/stuff/random" and it showed the result : " No such file or directory" so my question is is it possible or not to create multiple directories at a time ?

Comment: same for moving into multiple directories ?

Answer (score 3):

You need to add the `-p` argument (make parent directories as needed). So your command would be:

> mkdir -p temp/thing/stuff/random